# How to get value inside Thread

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, android-asynctask

**Context:**

I have a thread, inside the thread what I do is check if a URL exists or not. and I need to retrieve the value of the "urlExist" variable to use outside the method.

**Code**

```
fun checkIfUrlExist(url: URL):Boolean{
        object : Thread() {
            override fun run(): Boolean {
                super.run()
                try {
                    val con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                    con.requestMethod = "HEAD"
                    con.connect()
                    Log.i("myEndpoint", "con.getResponseCode() IS : " + con.responseCode)
                    if (con.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        urlExist = true //I need to get this
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }.start()
        
        if(urlExist){  //if the variable "urlExist" is true, I need to return true.
            return true
        }
    }
```

**Question:**

How can I get the value of the urlExsit variable?

Comment: Why are you using a separate thread if you want the result synchronously? Or are you unfamiliar with what asynchronous code is? If you want to do it without blocking the calling thread, use a callback or coroutine. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57330766/506796

Comment: Why are you using `urlExist` variable, just return true or false, and call `checkIfUrlExist` to get the result

Answer (score 0):

You already have urlExist variable outside the Thread you can just use it. You just need to mind that's a async problem.

If you need to run some logic after

```
con.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
```

check, what I suggest:

1. Move all the logic to a method. If you want to access the URL after the check, move all the logic that actually access the url to a "acessURL" method.
2. Call method right after `urlExist = true` or after the If statement, depending on your need.

If you have available time, It's worth to re-check your code. This is the case where you may need to use RxJava or LiveData